# Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource. for getUserpermissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-rest-api, java-api

I am trying to get permissions of user by consuming REST api from Java Client and after executing code . it shows

> Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource

Here is the URL:

```
https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/_api/web/getUserEffectivePermissions('i%3A0%23.f%7Cmembership%7Cprasad.shelke%40xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

From your error message it seems that you are using `getUserEffectivePermissions` method with the user login which does not have permission to run `getUserEffectivePermissions` this method.

**Make sure that you are using it with the user who has the admin rights** to get the user and permission detail.